# Fixing bootstrap collapsed navbar width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

below is my bootstrap code for my collapsible navbar. Everything seems ok except when I resize my window the collappsed one appears based on what the "min-width" contains. However if I attempt to increase the "min-width" over 1100px, the space between the logo and the links expand. Any ideas on how to fix this? I just want the collapible navbar to appear as soon as i adjust the window size. PS the logo is the navbar-brand, i added the image in css.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="50">
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="s_home.html"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse" style="min-width:1100px">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right links">
      <li><a href="#featured">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#mission">Software & Web Developer</a></li>
      <li><a href="#services">Game Development</a></li>
      <li><a href="s_art_design.html">Arts & Designs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#testimonials">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>        
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: min-width:1100px]

[image: min-width:1400px]

Comment: Get your coding done on jsfiddle so that I can have a look

Comment: i have to apologize i do not know how to use jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

can u share the code including the logo section too. 
if u cant.
then try giving

{
  `float:left;`
}
to the logo section
Explanation:

the logo might be acquiring the area.

Comment: .navbar-brand{
 padding-top:20px;
 background:url(../images/logo.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 height:50px;
 width:260px;
}